# Why does Lung the Quick's tombstone read "No Unicorns in Heaven"?

Tags: comics, ursula-vernon, digger

I'm reading *Digger*, and there's a scene in chapter six where Mural is crying next to a tombstone that reads "No Unicorns in Heaven."

What does the tombstone mean?

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://diggercomic.com/blog/2008/01/13/digger-309/) the scene you're talking about (click for full-size version):

[image: frame]

As mentioned in the comments on the page linked above, the backstory of Lung the Quick is explained in more detail in [the first Digger book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/cka/Digger-Vol-1-Ursula-Vernon/0976921227). If you don't have the book, it's also summarised [here](http://allthetropes.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorn) (OK, that site isn't a reliable source in itself, but it's sourced directly to the book) as follows:

> A book-only expansion to Digger tells us the story of a sculpter "commissioned" by a mad emperor, who had a forehead deformity and believed himself to be part-unicorn, to create statues of unicorns and nothing else. The artist came to hate unicorns, and dreamed of creating a perfect statue of the god Ganesh, which he accomplished after the emperor tried to eat poison and died. The epitaph on his tombstone reads, "There are no unicorns in Heaven."